# Access management in web application deployed as App Engine in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am developing a web application in GCP. I need to give role-based access management in my app. Are there any API's available in GCP to handle access management in my web application?

Comment: You have the following [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/libraries) for the APIs available for IAM. Please check if the mentioned documentation helps you.

Comment: As far as I understood, those libraries handles IAM for GCP components and services. I am looking for role based access management within my own custom application hosted in GCP. I don't want to add my end users in GCP. Let me know if I misunderstood it. Example use case in my application, I have courses in my web app which has roles like Teacher, Student. Each role has certain permission like Teacher can able to edit and upload resources in Courses while student can only view it. Is such use cases can be achieved through any available API in Google Cloud?

Comment: Not using only Google Cloud services. Google can manage the authentication (login), but the authorization (custom roles) must be managed by your application logic. Most frameworks provide login and RBAC features that you customize to meet your requirements. Google does not provide that as a service.

Comment: @JohnHanley can you please post your comment as an answer for visibility?

Answer (score 1):

Posting @JohnHanley comment as an answer for better visibility:

> Not using only Google Cloud services. Google can manage the authentication (login), but the authorization (custom roles) must be managed by your application logic. Most frameworks provide login and RBAC features that you customize to meet your requirements. Google does not provide that as a service.

So the conslusion is: Your requirement can be met with specific application logic.